# How to convert from ascii code to split character C#

Tags: c#, char, ascii

I am trying to convert the char Dec = 150 and Hex = 96 listed in this article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hxt0028(v=vs.80).aspx

My string is: AÛ5ÛÛBÛ4ÛÛCÛ3ÛÛDÛ2ÛÛEÛ1ÛÛFÛ0Û

I have tried so far:....

```
string[] allowedValues1 = allowedVals1.Split((char)150);

string[] allowedValues1 = allowedVals1.Split((char)96);

string[] allowedValues1 = allowedVals1.Split('\u0096');

string[] allowedValues1 = allowedVals1.Split('\x0096');

string[] allowedValues1 = allowedVals1.Split((Convert.ToChar(150)));
```

what shall work?

Comment: yes works that way but why doesnt ascii part work?

Comment: `Û` has code 219 (0xdb) and you are using `-` 150 (0x96) for some reason. Very unclear why you believe that should work or what kind of help you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code.

```
string test = "AÛ5ÛÛBÛ4ÛÛCÛ3ÛÛDÛ2ÛÛEÛ1ÛÛFÛ0Û";
int ascii = (int)'Û';
Console.WriteLine("ascii value of 'Û' is: " + ascii.ToString());
string[] allowedValues1 = test.Split((char)219);
```

If you want to remove empty values from array use :-

```
string[] allowedValues1 = test.Split( new char[] { (char)219 }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

See below snapshot of watch window with ascii value and split-ted array.

[image]