# Split a string with Backslash

Tags: c#, string, list

I'm trying to split a long string with a lot of data in it. The data come with a separator character '\r', I wanted to place each row into a `List<>` and carry out a `string.split()`. When I use the backslash as separator this doesn't work. I have read the below thread but it doesn't help me cause it still won't separate the data into rows. The idea was to crate a list and place later all info in a datagridview. Therefore I need to split all separate information

[Split string with backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783616/split-string-using-backslash)

This is the code I have tried (next to many other things)

```
 private void ExtractMeasurements (string Data)
    {
        int TotalMeasurements = frmMain.MeasTotal;
        List<string> Measurements = new List<string>();
        Measurements.AddRange(Data.Split('\\'));
    }
```

This is how the raw string looks like:

[image]

And here the result when I try to split the string

[image]

Am I making somewhere a silly mistake or is my strategy completely wrong?

Comment: Can you add a sample of the "data"?

Comment: Why not `Measurements.AddRange(Data.Split('\r'));` ?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp exactly what I was thinking. Wanted to be sure by seeing the string data first haha.

Comment: @ElectricRay81 `"\r"`  does not actually contain a backslash and an "r". It is just a textual representation of the carriage return. ASCII code 13. See also: [Escape Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences?view=msvc-170)

Comment: @ Johnny Mopp The '\r' I tried before but was not accepted, I think I have made that time a error or so. Because you mentioned it here I have tried it again and now it does what I expected.

Comment: @Jeff B Unfortunately I can't add the data here because I read it from a device connected to my pc via a serialport

Answer (score 2):

Adopted from this answer: [How to convert from ascii code to split character C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43358978/how-to-convert-from-ascii-code-to-split-character-c-sharp) and @Johnny Mopp's comments on the OP's questions.

This could be an approach that works for you. This uses the actual ASCII code as the value to split on. Being that ASCII code 13 is the `Carriage Return`.

```
Measurements.AddRange(Data.Split((char)13));
```

Comment: Yes this is another solution. I don't know what happened in the beginning but when I read the comments from VS I thought I can use only one char between de quotation marks. Obviously I have made a mistake all works perfect now. Thanks for the comments. I can start extracting further now everything in columns

Comment: Glad to help! Technically it is still a single `char`. `\r` and `(char)13` evaluate into the same value, `Carriage Return`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the issue was solved easily (with something I wanted to do from the start).

```
private void ExtractMeasurements (string Data)
    {

        int TotalMeasurements = frmMain.MeasTotal;

        List<string> Measurements = new List<string>();

        Measurements.AddRange(Data.Split('\r'));

    }
```

This gives me the following result:

[image]

Comment: The only reason I would side on the use of `(char)13` over `\r` is purely from the point of view that having less hard coded strings is always best =P. But in reality either method probably works equally.